# How to change Jquery slider image priority on link click

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dotnetnuke

Below is the img path that change at run time i got through the console, i have got 5 anchor tag through which i need to change the slider image priority and then it will move ahead in the order.

```
<img src="/Portals/0/concept.jpg" class="nivo-main-image" style="width: 802px; height: 319px;">
```

in the above img tag the image changes dynamically.

like on link 2 click i want to start the slider from img basic.jpg, so that i am changing through the Jquery like this

```
$("#hidelink2").click(function () {
            $(".nivo-main-image").attr('src', "http://localhost:50493/Portals/0/Basic.jpg");
            $(".div1").hide();
            $(".div2").show();
            $(".div3").hide();
            $(".div4").hide();
            $(".div5").hide();
        })
```

but it is not working what may be reason, could some body help me with this where i need to change.

Comment: can you put up a fiddle please?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your jQuery in a

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 // your linking code
});
```

Hard to solve this with so little of the code provided. You may also want to look at your Slider plugin javascript code. See if there is something on the jquery plugin you can call to move the order versus writing your own code and trying to manipulate it.